# creaky sound when cranking

Tags: repair

My bike seems to all of a sudden developed a creaking sound when I pedal. It appears to be there in every gear. Bu t I noticed it appears to only happen when I put pressure on the left pedal. What could it be ?

Comment: could be a few things but bottom bracket springs to mind. How often do you hear the creak? once per pedal revolution?

Comment: Search this site for noisy/creaky bottom bracket, there are already hundreds of answers.

Comment: yeah it's about once every revolution

Comment: The most critical possibility is that a crank arm is loose on the crank shaft.  If this is the case then the crank arm can be damaged in short order, so you should check the crank arm **immediately** and tighten it if there is **any** play at all between arm and shaft.  Beyond that, pedals and bottom brackets often make nose for no real reason.  Sometimes tightening the BB cups will fix the noise, but it's not a emergency.

Comment: Another possibility is a crack in the crank arm itself. Check for cracks (possibly very small) especially around where the pedal is screwed in to the arm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be:

- The pedal itself (even if it moves freely)
- The other pedal
- The bottom bracket
- The saddle
- Loose crank

Try to isolate each one of these by taking the weight off each in turn.

I was recently convinced my saddle was creaking as it only happened when sitting down but it turned out to be the left pedal!

Comment: Recently I tracked a creak when cranking to a loose headset.